# SLDS SVG creation and Partner users

Tags: slds

In one of my lightning component, I am creating an SVG icon( I followed the instruction on the SLDS site).

Everything works great except when a Partner User is trying to use my component. All the functionality is there except that my component does not render the SVG image.

Comment: Does the domain URL change when your partner logs in ? Do you see any errors in javascript console?

Comment: You are right Mohit, we use a completely different URL.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Do you have an idea on how to "dynamically" set the URL correctly. I hardcoded the community URL of our production environment in there but would love to find a way to have it work in our various sandbox environments.

Comment: If you can share the code ,I can help you through